# Büchi automaton to Linear Temporal Logic

Tags: automata, linear-temporal-logic, buchi-automata

Given a Büchi automaton what is the procedure to build an equivalent LTL formula? And what is its size?

I'm looking for references but I haven't found them so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Büchi automata are strictly more expressive than LTL, such a translation is not possible in the general case.

For instance, the language $L = \{w_0 w_1 w_2 \ldots \in (2^{\{a\}})^\omega \mid \exists^\infty i \in \mathbb{N}. w_{2i} = \{a\} \}$ is representable by a Büchi automaton with 3 states, but is not expressible in LTL as it is a *counting* language.

Comment: Do you know how to translate a counter-free Buchi automaton in LTL ? I  am moslty interested in it.

Comment: @kafka There is an answer for that case on mathoverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96963/translate-a-buchi-automaton-to-ltl